# Executing RESTful URL with Android

Tags: java, android, url, rest, restful-url

I am trying to exectue the following REST url using Android but I get the following error,

> 11-23 12:12:32.749: E/AndroidRuntime(709): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at
>   index 121:
>   http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/add.php?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx&type=Timbuktu&description=Africa&latitude=16.776767&longitude=-3.006361&private={"tag":"test"}

When I call the same URL in a browser, it works. Any help would be apprciated !

Comment: URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode your url first, paramerters part only..

```
 URLEncoder.encode("key=xxxx&type=Timbuktu&description=Africa&latitude=16.776767&longitude=-3.006361&private={\"tag\":\"test\"}", "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Hey, I'm just trying this now but keep getting, {"status":"error","message":"Missing type parameter in http request"} back from the server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to URL-encode the parameters of your URL, like this:

```
String privateParamValue = URLEncoder.encode("{\"tag\":\"test\"}", "UTF-8");
String url = "http://xxxx.com/add.php?key=xxxx&type=Timbuktu&description=Africa&latitude=16.776767&longitude=-3.006361&private=" + privateParamValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are intelligent and encode the URL in UTF-8. I Think u should also do that at client end.

```
URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```